# Angular won't display object

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

So i'm busy with a webapplication and i'm stuck now with parsing an object. What I just tried to do is getting the ID of all results but it gives me undefined back in my console.

What did i try:

```
    var app = angular.module("DB", []);

    app.controller("Controller", function($scope, $http) {
      $http.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
        $http.get('api_url').

        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.games = data.results;
          $scope.id = data.results.id; 
         //Do i need a foreach here because it doesn't loop through all records and it gives me undefined.

        $http.get('http:/api/id/' + $scope.id + '?api_key=', function(e){ 

        }).
          success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.details = data;
            console.log(data);
            //this returns the complete JSON
          });
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          //handle errors
      });
    });
```

the first http.get loops through a JSON like:

```
"results": [
    {
    "easy": false,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "title",
    },
    {
    "easy": false,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "title",
    },
    {
    "easy": true,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "title",
    }
]
```

and what the second on needs to do is get all of the ID's from the JSON and start a new GET:

```
$http.get('http:/api/id/' + $scope.id + '?api_key=', function(e){ 

}).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.details = data;
    console.log(data.data);
  });
})
```

the problem is that is, is that  `$scope.id = data.results.id;` is returing nothing, do i need a foreach or something to loop through it all?

And displaying it i did try:

```
 <div ng-repeat="detail in details">
    {{ detail }}
    {{ detail.adult }}
</div>
```

but is does not display anything (fyi i changed $scope.id = data.results.id; to $scope.id = data.results[0].id; to test it)

the JSON for the second GET looks like:

```
{
  "adult": false,
  "collection": {
    "id": 131295,
    "name": "Collection",
  },
  "levels": [{
    "id": 28
  }, {
    "id": 12
  }, {
    "id": 878
  }],
  "homepage": "google",
  "id": 100402,
  "overview": "lorem ipsum"
}
```

i can't access the object with {{ detail.adult }} for example.

Comment: Are you interacting with a RESTful entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `data.results.id` is returning nothing is because `data.results` is an Array of objects. If what you want is an Array with the IDs of the objects of `data.results` you could do it like this:

```
var resultIDs = data.results.map(function(result){return result.id;});
```

I'm not sure, but I think that this is what you want:

```
var app = angular.module("DB", []);

app.controller("Controller", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.details = [];
  $http.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
  $http.get('api_url').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.games = data.results;
      for(var i =0;i<$scope.games.lenght;i++){
         $http.get('http:/api/id/' + $scope.games[i].id + '?api_key=', function(e){ 

          }).
          success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              $scope.details.push(data);
          });
       }
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      //handle errors
  });
});
```

However **I would check if the API that you are using has a method that accepts an array of IDs instead of a single ID, so that you don't have to iterate like that**.

If this API is a RESTful service you could do it without iterating, like this:

```
var app = angular.module("DB", []);

app.controller("Controller", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.details = [];
  $http.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
  $http.get('api_url').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      $scope.games = data.results;
      var resultIDs = data.results.map(function(result){return result.id;});
       $http.get('http:/api?id=' + resultIDs.join(',') + '?api_key=', function(e){ 

       }).
       success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.details = data;
       });
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      //handle errors
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi @Josep , thanks. Now i'm getting all of the ids in an array but what i want is that ` $http.get('http:/api/id/' + $scope.id + '?api_key=', function(e){ ` the $scope.id is getting replaced with the ID so i can access the data in that JSON file

Comment: @Frenck I've updated the answer, let me know if that's what you were looking for, thanks!

Comment: thank you very much it helped me in the right direction. The only thing is that i got an error with the result.length i guess 'ReferenceError: results is not defined'

Comment: @Frenck my bad, I have updated the answer, have a look at it, and please try the second option.